# What is the best free FTP server for Mac OS X Server?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, osx-server, ftp

I'm running Mac OS X Snow Leopard server on a mac mini and was wondering what the best free FTP server was? I hear okay things about pure-ftpd but I'd like something with an easy to manage UI as well etc...

Comment: Mac OS X Server comes with an FTP server built in.  Is there something specific you're looking for that it doesn't do?

Comment: I had just ready it was very performant or feature rich in a lot of ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you’re planning on running an extremely heavy loaded FTP server (which the mini won’t be able to handle anyway) the built in FTP Server should be enough.

Pure-ftpd is a classic in the Unix world and I’m sure you can of course make that run under OS X, but it doesn’t have a “UI”, it’s all command line. (But very easy to configure anyway).

Comment: How about Desktop Snow Leopard ? FileZilla works or any native OS X software available ? Looking for Free/ Opensource one.

Comment: @Garikapati I don’t know about Filezilla (which has an OSX port), but Pure-pftpd also has been natively compiled for OSX. Those are servers, native ftp clients for OSX are quite a lot, some free and open source (http://cyberduck.ch/).

Answer (score 1):

***edit**: sorry, speed read and missed the part about best **free** server. Rumpus is not free.*

Hands down best FTP server for OS X is [Rumpus](http://www.maxum.com/Rumpus/). We use it at work to deliver content to clients and also to receive content from providers. Extremely easy to use, but is also very configurable. We have been using it for years & he dev has always replied to our emails within 24hrs.

Worth a try, it will not disappoint!

Comment: Just wasted an hour of my life on rumpus. Written by someone stuck in the 90. Lots of useless features for someone not in the "enterprise". Could not get to work with a per user folder permissions. Rather I had to use a whole directory. Also, it seems that symlinks don't work so good luck with copying files everything you want to grant access to another user.

Answer (score 0):

The built in web server is great, and the Server Admin tools in Mac OS Server also make managing the machine awesome as well.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. The build in FTP is great.

But Symbolic Links show up as binaries as soon as the mapped driver is not on the system it self but an network share.

So it's is not usable for me. And there is no alternative that has the same quality standards as OS X.
I've been asking all over the place but the question is asked several times no one has an answer. That is a pitty.

Gr.
LeoFric

Comment: Please ask your question as it's own - the OP might not care about the limitation you see, but until you ask that specific question - it won't likely get an answer here among other potential answers